# Descriptive Statistic for each variable under List data type in R

Tags: r

So, I am trying to figure out how to display the descriptive statistics for the data type: List (let's say it called runs) and having 3 variables. I would like to have all descriptive stats for those 3 variables.

I have looked into these:

```
library(pastecs)
stat.desc(mydata) 
nbr.val, nbr.null, nbr.na, min max, range, sum, 
median, mean, SE.mean, CI.mean, var, std.dev, coef.var
```

When I run `stat.desc(runs)`, it only shows one result.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q4/009072.html), especially without mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Try lapply with the function basicStats from the fBasics library.

Something like this might work:

```
library(fBasics)

lapply(runs,basicStats)
```

Comment: got this error: lapply(runs,basicStats)
Error in min(X) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: Really? I tried with: runs <- list(A=c(1,2,4,2,2),B=rnorm(5,2,2),C=rpois(5,2)) and it did. Maybe if you add your list we can help a bit more.

Comment: I need to change the list to data frame first so I can use the function instead. 
Thanks anyone for the input

Answer (score 0):

How about accessing "data members" of the list with `my.list[[i]]`?

Comment: This one works showing the data member for particular observation only.

Comment: vip, could you please post the code that you used to try my suggestion?